# how to add help text on websites?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, textbox

I have made a websites with basic forms and tables, I am entering using the forms which are displaying data in an organize manner in the tables.

I need to add the help link to the text boxes of the form. 
For example I have a textbox with "target address" label, I want to add a little question mark in front of that label [just like this](https://pythonhosted.org/django-jqm/_images/form5-1.png) , so that when user clicks on it, it display the text "enter the ip address to trigger the target device".
 I want to add help link in front of every text box label, so that user can see the details what he should enter and in what format.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the *title* property:

```
<div title="This is a div"></div>
```

When the mouse is over the div, a yellow box will show up.

If you want to use a physical button, you'll have to create a div or button for each text entry.

```
<div onclick="javascript: showTip();">?</div>
```

**A much cleaner method**, in my opinion, would be to use a *placeholder* (only for input elements):

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Insert your name"/>
```

The input will contain that text until the user clicks on the text entry.
**The placeholder attribute is new in HTML5**

Answer (score 0):

```css
.tooltip {
  border : solid 1px lightgrey;
  color : lightgrey;
  border-radius : 100px;
  font-size : 9px;
  padding-left : 4px;
  padding-right : 4px;  
  margin-left : 4px;
}

.tooltip:hover {
  cursor : pointer; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input placeholder = "target adress" /><span id = "tooltip_targetAdress" class = "tooltip" title = "target adress is used to do things">?</span>
```

`title` attribute is made for this. If you want something more customized, you will need to work on a div showed on click but it is more work for such a simple thing.